# find_by_sql renders an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count

I got some problems here, I can't make my find_by_sql request to render an ActiveRecord relation. Indeed, I need an activerecord relation to make a new request:

```
@searches = @searches.find_by_sql('SELECT *, COUNT( follower_id ) FROM follows GROUP BY followable_id LIMIT 0 , 3') if params[:only_famous_projects]
@project_pages = @project_pages.where(:project_id => @searches.pluck(:'followable.id')) if params[:only_famous_projects]
```

I can't use "pluck" without an activerecord relation. Therefore, I think I have to convert my sql request to an Activerecord request. However, as soon as I use "count" on ActiveRecord, I have an huge problem: I don't have on the end an ActiveRecord relation, but a FixNum!

I don't know where to find the answer anymore, I would be really gratefull if you could help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_by_sql` will return an ActiveRecord object only if you call it with `YourModel.find_by_sql`.

Why not use the ActiveRecord query interface. It does a good job with calculations.

**UPDATED**

```
@searches = @searches.group(:followable_id).limit(3).offset(0).count(:follower_id) if params[:only_famous_projects]
```

Notice that it will give you a Hash containing the count for each `followable_id`.

Isn't `LIMIT 0, 3` equivalent to `LIMIT 3` ?

Comment: Thanks;
However, it is on the "follow" table; So i put on my console:

    `@searches = Follow.count(:follower_id).group(:followable_id).limit(3).offset(0)`

And it returned me:

`NoMethodError: undefined method group for 8:Fixnum`

I suspect "count" to return a fixnum, making impossible to do other method on it

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` will always return a FixNUM, because you asked the database to count the number of rows.

You should really try to use `find_by_sql` as a last resort as it is only meant to bypass ActiveRecord for things that it can not do. And even for things that ActiveRecord doesn't support, you can always see if you can use the [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) or [Valium](https://github.com/ernie/valium) gems to handle edge-cases.

Another reason not to use `find_by_sql` is that, for example, using MySQL specific terms will lock you out of using other databases in the future.

Comment: Thanks you, therefore I should not use "count", for I need to get infos from several columns.
It seems that I can't use these gems, they don't allow me to "count" one specifically colum.

I should not use find_by_sql, but it seems I don't have the choice

Comment: @user1468585 Why not opt for doing the count in your application code instead of the query? Then you can get yourself the required ActiveRecord relation to use with `pluck`.