# How to use find_by_sql properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model

```
class Backup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :component
  belongs_to :backup_medium

  def self.search(value)
    join_tables = "backups, components, backup_media"
    joins = "backups.backup_medium_id = backup_media.id and components.id = backups.component_id"
    c = Backup.find_by_sql "select * from #{join_tables} where components.name like '%#{value}%' and #{joins}"
    b = Backup.find_by_sql "select * from #{join_tables} where backup_media.name  like '%#{value}%' and #{joins}"
    c.count > 0 ? c : b
  end
end
```

In pry, when I run Backup.all.class, I get

```
=> Backup::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

but when I run Backup.search('xxx').class, I get

```
=> Array
```

Since the search should return a subset of all, I think I need to return an Active Record_Relation.  What am I missing?

Comment: You should try to use the ActiveRecord query interface instead of relying on `find_by_sql`, so you'd have something like `Backup.joins(:components, :backup_media).where("components.name like '%#{value}%')` for the first query, which should return a `Backup::ActiveRecord_Relation`. 
`find_by_sql` is intended for more complex queries than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find\_by\_sql renders an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115785/find-by-sql-renders-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

`find_by_sql` returns an array of objects, not a `Relation`. If you want to return relation for consistency try to rewrite your search to use `ActiveRecord` api:

```
  def self.search(value)
    query = Backup.includes(:component, :backup_medium)
    by_component_name = query.where("components.name like ?", "'%#{value}%'")
    by_media_name = query.where("backup_media.name like ?", "'%#{value}%'")
    by_component_name.any? ? by_component_name : by_media_name
  end
```

or, if you still want to use sql, you can try to fetch record ids and then make a second query:

```
def self.search(value)
    # ...
    c = Backup.find_by_sql "select id from #{join_tables} where components.name like '%#{value}%' and #{joins}"
    b = Backup.find_by_sql "select id from #{join_tables} where backup_media.name  like '%#{value}%' and #{joins}"
    ids = c.count > 0 ? c : b
    Backup.where(id: ids)
  end
```

Comment: I really like your first suggestion, but I'm getting complaints because components.name is in the components table but not in the backups table.  backups just has the ids into the other two tables.

Comment: @P.H. the problem was probably in the `Backup.includes(...)` Please take a look at update answer, it should be `Backup.includes(:component, :backup_medium)`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Executes a custom SQL query against your database and returns all the
>   results. The results will be returned as an array with columns
>   requested encapsulated as attributes of the model you call this method
>   from. If you call Product.find_by_sql then the results will be
>   returned in a Product object with the attributes you specified in the
>   SQL query.

So you will get an array of Backup instances.

Note that you probably should not do it this way.  Using string interpolation in a query opens you up to SQL injection attacks and gains you nothing.  Also, you can get quite a bit more flexibility using ActiveRecord scopes for this.

```
def self.my_includes
  includes(:components, :backup_media)
end

def self.by_component_name(name)
  media_includes.where("components.name like ?", "'%#{name}%'")
end

def self.by_media_name(name)
  media_includes.where("backup_media.name  like ?", "'%#{value}%'")
end

def self.search(name)
  by_component(name).any? ? by_component_name : by_media_name
end
```

You can then call

```
Backup.search(name)
```

as well as

```
Backup.by_component_name(name)
```

or

```
Backup.by_media_name(name)
```

Comment: I will try remaking a sample application with this solution and I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

So I am unable to get the syntax right for the media_includes, but inspired by your solution I have succeeded by using joins.

I created a small demo project which just shows the code related to search.  You can take a look at https://github.com/pamh09/rails-search-demo.  If you want to collaborate on a solution, I think this would be more efficient than trying to paste all the code here.  That said, I do have a working solution if you'd rather not bother.  But I would like to see what the right syntax is.

Below is the model code.  It's very possible that I just have some kind of syntactic mismatch since I am not very familiar with how rails does its database magic (obviously).

```
class Backup < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :component
    belongs_to :backup_medium


#---- code below does not work ---
# in pry
# pry(Backup):1> by_media('bak').any?
# (0.0ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "backups" WHERE (backup_media = 'bak')
# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: backup_media.name:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "backups" WHERE (backup_media.name = 'bak')

def self.my_includes
      includes(:component, :backup_medium)
    end

    def self.by_component(name)
      my_includes.where("components.name = ?", name)
    end

    def self.by_media(name)
      my_includes.where("backup_media.name  = ?", name)
    end

    def self.search_by(name)
      by_component(name).any? ? by_component_name : by_media_name
    end

# ----- code below works ... call search('string') -----
# I was unable to get the like query to work without using #{name}

    def self.by_component_like(name)
  # Note: joins (singular).where (plural.column ...)
      joins(:component).where("components.name like '%#{name}%'")
    end

    def self.by_media_like(name)
      joins(:backup_medium).where("backup_media.name like '%#{name}%'")
    end

    def self.search(name)
      by_component_like(name).any? ? by_component_like(name) : by_media_like(name)
    end

end
```

And, as noted in the code.  I could not figure you how to use the ? with LIKE as the query would come in as LIKE '%'xxx'%' instead of '%xxx%'.